# SessionState expired behaviour

Tags: asp.net, session, redirect, webforms, session-state

Is it possible to control the behaviour of ASP.NET when the `Session` has expired? It seems that the default behaviour is sending the user to the website root. The desired effect would be to send the user to a custom "Session Expired" page.

To clarify, it's the `SessionState` that's expiring (set the timeout to 1 minute to quickly test it):

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

The authentication cookie timeout is way higher, to avoid any mix-up:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="SessionExpired.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" name=".ttpASPXAUTH" timeout="58" protection="All"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Do you mean authorization ticket expiration instead of SessionState expiration? When the SessionState expires you're redirected nowhere.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by redirected to root. If the user resubmits the page you still go back to the requesting page, the authorization/authentication handlers might redirect you to the login page if they are in place

Comment: It's not the authorization cookie that's expiring, it's the SessionState. Edited the question to add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the whole Authorization ticket/session state problem, but an easy way to redirect someone to a particular page when their session has expired is to put code into the Application_AcquireRequestState event in the Global.asax file to check for a session variable and if it doesn't exist, redirect to your "session expired" page.

Comment: Just tried this. The problem is that this Application_AcquireRequestState is hit on every single request, which means that trying to redirect from this event results in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch this in your global.asax in the Session_Start method.

I use something like this for simple sites:

```
if (!Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("DEFAULT.ASPX", _
              StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    string newPage = string.Format("ErrorPage.aspx?ErrorMessage={0}", _
              System.Uri.EscapeUriString("Your session has expired."));
    Logger.InfoFormat("{0} Session expired or illegal page access attempted: {1}", _
              Utility.StoreRegisterForLog, Request.Url.ToString());
    Response.Redirect(newPage);
}
```

If they're not on the home page, she gets sent to the error page with a message saying her session has expired.

Comment: So what you're saying here is that the Session can only be started from the home page. If for any reason the event is triggered from any other page, it means that it has expired and the app is trying to start it again. Right?